# populating drop down list from table data in android using Phonegap api?

Tags: html, cordova

i have to create something like combobox in android using html5 ,phonegap

Answer (score 1):

I would use Glovebox (http://purplecabbage.github.com/GloveBox/) to create a scrollable list, which is effectively all the standard Android combobox is.  The javascript source code on the example page shows you how to easily create it.

Comment: Why do you have to create a combobox?  You'll notice that in just about every mobile environment, the dropdown box no longer exists, or at least not in the way it does on the web.  Android has comboboxes, or "spinners", but they just open up easy to read lists like I mentioned. iOS's closest thing to a combobox would be a Picker.  

I would strongly suggest reconsidering your UI before finding a way to create this functionality that mobile OS vendors have basically purposely eliminated.

Comment: thanks for your response.something like suggestion box or google search